# wx.app object must be created first

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

My code is pretty straight forward, but I keep getting the error below. I researched the error and it pretty much says IDLE and my own GUI are screwing each other up, but I don't really know how to avoid it. I mean, if I just click on the .py file for my GUI without having IDLE open, I get the same error.

Any ideas?

**Python 2.7
Windows XP**

```
import wx

class applicationName(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, 'Title', size=(300,200))
        panel = wx.Panel(self)


    box = wx.TextEntryDialog(None, "How old are you?", "Title", "default text")
    if box.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        answer = box.GetValue()




if __name__ =='__main__':
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = applicationName(parent=None, id=-1)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

---

Error:

PyNoAppError: The wx.App object must be created first!

---

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `__init__` function is not indented properly.  It should be

```
 def __init__(self, parent, id):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, 'Title', size=(300,200))
    panel = wx.Panel(self)


    box = wx.TextEntryDialog(None, "How old are you?", "Title", "default text")
    if box.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        answer = box.GetValue()
```

Comment: That's really not a valid answer. I ran similar code. Worked first time, and now I get the same error of `wx.App object must be created first`

Answer (score 14):

I guess you encountered this problem when you were debugging your program second time.

You can add the line at the end of the code.

```
del app
```

I hope it can help you.

Comment: Thank you, I got this same problem (only while running my code the second time) and you solved it :-)

Comment: I think this is the correct answer as the checked answer didn't help but this one did.

Answer (score 3):

Quoted from: http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/PyNoAppError-The-wx-App-object-must-be-created-first-td2362821.html

> The key is to use an editor/IDE that runs the Python code you are 
>   editing in an external process, rather than running it in the same 
>   process as the editor itself.

Comment: Indeed, running the wxWidgets helloworld2.py example on https://wxpython.org/pages/overview/ in Spyder gave me this error. Setting the file configuration on "Execute in a dedicated console' made it work.

Answer (score 0):

Try closing the terminal/console and re-running it (if the option is available).
worked for me when i got this massage in Spyder (3.3.2) when ran similar code to the above.

Answer (score 0):

Running this inside Psychopy builder, adding the following to the beginning of the experiment helped:

```
import wx 
tmpApp = wx.PySimpleApp()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, but the:

```
del app
```

close the window and stop the kernel, so it was not of great help

I found that this worked for me:

```
app=[]; app = wx.App(None)
```

whitout the app=[]-part, the program run once, but not the second time when it stops and gives the "wx.app object must be created first"-error

Hope this can be of use for others.

Per